# mysql - Which method of building a database is more suitable for lightening the pressure on the server?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I consider two methods: one for each user to create a table with the users name and enter all the information in the table, or I store all the users profiles information in a large table.

Does the first method reduce server load, or doesn't have much different? Is there a problem in increasing the number of tables?

Comment: Why not test it?

Comment: If the number of users reaches millions, the difference is great

Comment: I can't imagine that there's much difference, but this kind of question is best directed to the dba forum

Comment: what is the dba?

Comment: Arbitrarily adding any number of tables to cover all your users won't scale well, and is not standard database design.  Having a central table shared by all users is the probably the way to go IMHO.

Comment: when all users call each and every information on a large table every time is not this a better way?

Comment: There are many threads on this Forum discussion table-per-user versus not -- Find and read them.